# Using only a direct object with the verb "give"

Tags: verbs, word-usage, direct-objects, indirect-objects

Is it possible to use the verb *give* with only a direct object? For example,

> Could you give the definition?

Or need I to add an indirect object, so the sentence becomes

> Could you give me the definition?

Comment: Yes, with _give_ it's perfectly normal to leave the receiver to be inferred in the context. With questions, it's normally the speaker, hence _to me_ is overkill. And, btw, with short words, especially pronouns, Dative movement is much more likely. I.e,  _Could you give me the definition?_ is better conversational English than _Could you give the definition to me?_

Comment: Sure, there are lots of cases where the indirect object (the recipient) is implied: “I don’t give money; I give only my time.” [or vice-versa]  In some cases, even the direct object can be implied: “Give until it hurts!” And then there are idioms where there ***is no*** indirect object / recipient, but I don’t give a damn about those.    :-)    ⁠

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot think of any English verb that *requires* an indirect object, so I cannot give an example of one.

As you can see, *give* is not such an example.

Comment: _Tell_ normally requires an indirect object, though not a direct object. That's one of the differences between _tell_ and _say_.

Comment: C'mon, @JohnLawler, tell the truth.

Comment: There are fixed phrases like _tell the truth_ and _tell shit from Shinola_, and special constructions (like [_That would be telling_](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/198276/15299)) with special meanings. But normal sentences using the verb _tell_ require an indirect object, but not a direct one. _She told me, but she'll never tell him. She told me that, but she'll never tell him that._ But not _*She told this, but she'll never tell that._

Comment: I see your point, that idiomatically, *tell* usually requires an indirect object.  You can say something in an empty room, but you cannot "tell" in that situation.  But there are so many of what you call "fixed phrases" -- *tell the story*, *kiss and tell*, *tell tales* -- it begins to look like regular usage.  *Tell shit from Shinola* is a different use of *tell*, meaning "to count, reckon, or enumerate" (as in *tell time*) or "to discern, notice, identify or distinguish" (as in, well, you know), that always takes a DO and never an IO.

Comment: There are many, many different meanings for **every** verb, depending on the constructions it appears in. That's why I keep harping on constructions instead of words. There's no end to words, but constructions are how the words are used.